# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- useful administration tools and resources
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2436).

Answer (score 20):

[image: Plan Explorer - Unrivaled execution plan analysis. Now completely free!]

Comment: You forgot to change "Tagline to show on mouseover". This cause the generic message to appear as tooltip on the actual ad, which isn't nice. (In my opinion. Better leave it empty if there's nothing else to show.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard How funny is that, I just noticed this 10 minutes ago. (Also, is there a way to refresh the image? I noticed because I was reviewing our re-branding efforts and I missed this one.) I changed the tagline but this hasn't refreshed on the site, I wonder if it's fixed or if it re-pulls from here occasionally?

Comment: hehe, cheers! I just saw the ad on homepage, hovered, and noticed the generic tooltip. What you mean "refresh the image"? Can't you just re-upload and change the URL?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can, but I have no idea if the ad rotation will ever pick this up again. It could be that the ad being served is a copy of the image, and editing this post will have no effect.

Comment: Oh, you mean to prevent abuse, since it got upvotes based on first image. Good point, I'll  try to dig it up and see

Comment: @Shadow Well, we'll see what happens I guess. :-) I can always revert.

Comment: Hmm... very weird. The updated picture appears in the [stats page](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2436), but after reloading the [homepage](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) about 100 times, the only single Community Promotion ad I saw is [this one](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/2439/39053). Not yours, and not the other two. Can you try to reload lots of times too and if same thing contact someone in the higher levels via your private channels? Something might be off.

Comment: @Shadow I see the same. I'm going to give it a 24-hour burn-in period, in case I invalidated the entire cache by making an edit and changing the image URL.

Comment: Hmm... this might be cross network issue, I'll try on other sites and if same behavior start MSE bug report.

Comment: @Shadow I've seen the SQL Saturday one below several times today.

Comment: I checked arqade and there too, only single ad out of [the seven](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/ads/display/11204) is shown, the Movies ad. Maybe they select one ad and show it for everyone for several hours, then choosing another? Will try tomorrow, though might be worth a question on MSE anyway.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Register to attend a free Microsoft SQL Server conference in your area.]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Free health check for Microsoft SQL Server.]